# Python 3.8 configure --with-openssl not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssl, openssl

Due to a system limitation, I have installed Python 3.8 and OpenSSL 1.1.1 in non-standard locations (/home/username/Python-3.8.0 and /home/username/openssl) and I have the openssl lib path exported in my .bashrc file. I ran configure
(`./configure --prefix=$HOME/Python-3.8.0 --with-openssl=$HOME/openssl`), but after `make`/`make install` I still get the following error. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

Here are some files for context.

`.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$HOME/openssl/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/opt/perl/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/openssl/lib
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LDFLAGS="-L $HOME/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/openssl/lib"
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
alias python3="$HOME/bin/python3.8"
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```

`Python-3.8.0/Modules/Setup`

```
...
#SSL=$HOME/openssl
#_ssl _ssl.c \
#       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
...
```

Comment: Did you build Python yourself?  If you do `find ~ -name '_ssl.*`, does it file the module?  And please note there is confusion in your posts between `$HOME/Python-3.8.0` and `$HOME/bin/python3.8`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did build Python myself. The server has an old version, but I'm not able to upgrade it. so I've installed it in my account's home directory. Searching for the module I see:

Comment: `/home/username/Python-3.8.0/PCbuild/_ssl.vcxproj
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/PCbuild/_ssl.vcxproj.filters
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_ssl.c
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/home/username/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_ssl.gcda
/home/username/Python-3.8.0/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/home/username/Python-3.8.0/Modules/_ssl.o`

Comment: OK, that's where you BUILT Python 3.8, but that's not where it runs.  Did you then run the install script?  Someone needs to copy `~/Python-3.8.0/lib` into `~/lib/python3.8`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I ran the install and everything is copied into ~/lib/python3.8. Python3 is running fine, but the openssl configuration just didn't seem to take for some reason.

Comment: To cheat, try `cp ~/Python-3.8.0/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl* ~/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload`.